# Why subtract a value from itself (x - x) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

In NumPy functions, there are often initial lines that do checking of variable types, forcing them to be certain types, etc.  Can someone explain the point of these lines in [scipy.signal.square](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html)?  What does subtracting a value from itself do?

```
t,w = asarray(t), asarray(duty)
w = asarray(w + (t-t))
t = asarray(t + (w-w))
```

[source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/waveforms.py#L55-L56)

Comment: This is a guess so I'm not going to put it as an answer, but it seems likely that not all zeros are of the same type.  This generates the zero of whatever numerical type is being used here, I'm guessing.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it triggers some type coercion that lets NumPy make performance optimizations.

Comment: It would be nice if they had used comments.

Comment: Comments?  The code was hard to write.  It should be hard to read!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe that this will make the final w and t have the same type. For example, if you start with float and int, you will end up with both being float arrays which is better for subsequent operations.

Comment: yes, and it will have the same dimension as well ( in case they started out with different)

Comment: That's kind of weird considering t is an array and w is a scalar

Comment: @endolith: No, self, they're not.  w can actually vary over time, producing PWM waveforms, for example, as I added to the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.square.html#scipy.signal.square